# How much data can fit in XMLHttpRequest response?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I get truncated responses on the client side while transferring back a javascript array (literal) to the client. I was wondering if there is a size limit for the response. Suggestions on how to handle this problem are very welcome.

On the client side I evaluate the response:

```
var r = eval(response.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

on the server side an array is sent back :

```
Error: unterminated string literal
Source File: 
Line: 144, Column: 3530
Source Code:
[['f1','13/03/2012 12:55:18','4543634952F01129AD7D0414855DBC52',
 ['2006','mir','note','pachet','pdf']],
 ['f10','13/03/2012 12:55:18','turnbull-taggin_music_sound-aslp2008',
 ['autotagging','missing','note','pdf']],
 ...
 ['f35','13/03/2012 12:55:18','ECML2001',['2001','note','pdf','syno
```

Comment: no size limits that i know of, just time to process the request and return the value, paste some of your code plz.

Comment: I updated the question to better explain. The error is on the client, the array is send by the server.

Comment: Use a debugger such as Firebug to see the whole response prior to processing. See what you get.

Comment: what about your client side code? there's nothing wrong with your server side code

Comment: The server just send an array that is evaluated on the client side. As the response is truncated, I get an error. I am still investigating the problem. I found the response was truncated after 4096 characters. Does it ring a bell ?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question. The problem is browser-specific and due to a limitation in Firefox. In short, Firefox limits the size of XML nodes to 4k and splits the original value over multiple child nodes.

Mode details here : http://www.coderholic.com/firefox-4k-xml-node-limit/.

Comment: *I can answer my own question* Do not forget to mark it as answered.